# saving a struct that has dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary, codable

I have created a stuct that has a few values. I was trying to save to `UserDefaults`. That didn't work as it I kept getting a SIGBRT error. I did some research and I realized that I will have to conform to the `Codable` protocol as saving straight to user defaults (even using `NSArchiver` - won't do the job).

I learned the this new method (`Codable`) and everything worked flawlessly until I added a dictionary to my struct. Every time I add a dictionary (I have a lot of dictionaries I need to work with) `[Int: String]`, `[Int:UIImage]`, `[Int:[String]]`, and `[Int:[UIIMage]]`. Everytime, I add any of these dictionaries to my struct, I get an error saying that my struct does not conform to protocol `Codable`. If I remove the dictionary variables, everything works fine.

Any help would be great. I did a lot of research, and people are talking about JSON, not sure what that is, not working with web at all, everything is local on my app.

```
struct Student: Codable {
    var name: String
    var dictOne: [Int:String] = [:]
    var dictTwo: [Int:[String]] = [:]
    var dictThree: [Int:UIImage] = [:]
}
```

Comment: I presume that you are trying to save into `UserDefaults` - You can't save a `UIImage` directly to UserDefaults or JSON.  You will either need to encode the image using Base64 or similar, or save the images as files and just store the file path.

Comment: I managed to save images to user defaults before. All you have to do is archive the variable, or array, or dictionary, then save it. Then unarchive it and use it. thats no problem. My issue deals with why a struct that has dictionaries doesn't conform to type codable. thnx

Comment: You can save them if you us `NSArchiving`, but you have switched to using `Codable`.  `UIImage` supports `NSArchiving`, but not `Codable`.  For a struct to conform to `Codable` all of its properties must conform to `Codable`

Comment: ok fair enough, do you know how to make it work with NSarchiving then? every time I try to archive the struct and save it, the app crashes with a SIGBRT error. thnx a lot

Comment: You should edit your question to show the code you have tried

Comment: @Paulw11 I was fooling around with the code and you are 100% correct about the UIImages being the problem. can you link me to a page where I can learn to do as suggested (encoding the image using Base64 or saving the images to files and referring to the URL. My images are currently as PNG files saved in the assets.xcassets folder. thnx

Comment: If the images are in your asset catalog, then all you need to do is save the image name so that you can retrieve it via `UIImage(named:)`.  There is no point in saving the image itself multiple times.

Comment: Also, a dictionary with Integer keys looks suspicious; It could possibly be replaced with a simple array.